# DPM 2007 clashing with existing SQL backup job

Tags: sql-server-2005, scdpm

I've recently installed a DPM2007 server on Server 2003 and have set up a protection group against a server 2003 server running SQL 2005 SP3.

The SQL server in question has a full backup (as a sql agent job) once a day and transaction log backups hourly. These are zipped up and FTP'd to a server offsite by a scheduled task.

Since adding the DPM job I'm receiving many error messages:

> DPM tried to do a SQL log backup,
>   either as part of a backup job or a
>   recovery to latest point in time job.
>   The SQL log backup job has detected a
>   discontinuity in the SQL log chain for
>   database SERVER_NAME\DB_Name since the
>   last backup. All incremental backup
>   jobs will fail until an express full
>   backup runs.

My google-fu suggests that I need to change the full backup my sqlagent job is running to a copy_only job. But I think this means that I can't use that backup with the transaction_logs to restore the database if the building (including the DPM server) burns down.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious and thought I'd see what the hivemind suggests.

It is an option to set-up a co-located DPM server elsewhere and have DPM stream the backup but that's obviously more expensive than the current set up.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google-fu is correct.  When your full backup runs from the SQL Agent job, the RESTORE chain for the DPM backup sequence is broken, and DPM no longer has context on the previous log files.

Running the SQL Agent backup as copy-only will work, as it does not break the RESTORE chain.  Taking a full backup with this option does not make the new backup a new base - it does not clear any of the differential bitmaps and doesn't interfere with the DPM backups.

It's difficult to maintain two backup chains simultaneously, as each one will interfere with the other.

Comment: I was worried someone would confirm that :) Off to set up an offsite dpm server it is...

Answer (score 0):

I hate to hijack a question, but I am having the same problem and I am using the agent to backup the transaction log so that it can be shrunk. Since I was told that DPM 2007 doesn't truncate the logs after backing them up, I was forced to use the agent since I had a few log files that were over 40GB each. Am I missing something on the log file backup in DPM that it can truncate them?

Comment: you're more likely to get an answer if you ask your own question as your question doesn't match my question title and this question is marked as answered so people are less likely to look at it.